# how to find out if a shell command exists in cshell

Tags: shell, command-line, csh

I'm looking for a function that would return 1 if a shell command exists, and 0 otherwise
I know there is the `which` command that returns the path of a command if it exists. It also says in the manual that this command is supposed to have a return value, but trying
set `` a = `which some_command.bin` `` doesn't put any value into `a`. 
I know that I can always use `which` then parse the results, I'm just looking for a cleaner solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value for a shell command is not usually retrieved like that. You generally need to run the command, then the special environment variable `$?` will give you the return value.

See the following transcript for `tcsh`:

```
pax$ which qq ; echo $?
qq: Command not found.
1

pax$ which ls ; echo $?
/bin/ls
0
```

Just put whatever command you want to check for where I have `ls` above.

Comment: I dont want to run the shell command, just want to know if it exists or not

Comment: maybe i didnt understand you, I ran which and the $? and it worked :) Thanks!!

Comment: @n00b, it's not running the command, it's running `which` with the command as a parameter. I'm just illustrating how you can get the return value from `which` so you can figure out if the command exists or not.